# jQuery does not stop propagation of `jQuery.click()` on native event-handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use [`jQuery.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to simulate user clicks in our tests. We noticed the following oddity:

Event-handlers that are registered natively are called even if `event.stopPropagation()` is called when [`jQuery.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) is used.

Using the native [`HTMLelement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) correctly stops propagation.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

## Example:

Given the following HTML:

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```js
window.document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function () {
    console.log('document clicked</li>')
  }
)

$('button').on(
  'click', 
  function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log('event propagation stopped</li>')
  }
)

// Using jQuery.click() method logs both, in this order:
// * event propagation stopped
// * document click
$('button').click()

// Using the native HTMLElement.click() stops the propagation of the event:
// * event propagation stopped
$('button')[0].click()
```

You can find an example here: https://jsbin.com/qekuda/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please have a look https://jsbin.com/vusorukoda/1/edit?html,js,output .... Use isPropagationStopped() method instead of stopPropagation(). stopPropagation() method is not available inside event. Check the console log as well.

Comment: @Shiladitya: `isPropagationStopped()` has no side-effects and returns a boolean. `stopPropagation()` on the other hand, well, stops propagation. Therefor it makes sense that your code does not stop the propagation. The problem I am describing is that the event propagation is **not stoped**.